# How do I use Adobe Acrobat's "combine supported files in Acrobat" feature from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, pdf, adobe-acrobat

The Windows version of Adobe Acrobat (not Adobe Reader) has a feature where I can select a group of files and hit "Combine supported files in Acrobat" in the context menu and it will present me with a menu to merge them. Is there a way to access this feature from the command line? I found [Acrobat's command line documentation](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/DevFAQ_UnderstandingSDK.22.31.html) which lists a paltry set of features, so this might not be possible.

Is there documentation on how to do this? `acrobat.exe /?` and `help acrobat.exe` do nothing. The latter tells me to use the former and the former opens acrobat and tells me it couldnt find the file named `/?`

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the combine files function is supported via command line; you may try passing more than one file name and see what happens, however.

For such a task, on Mac, I would use Automator or create an AppleScript droplet. I am not sufficiently familiar with the Windows version, but there, it should be possible to create something using IAC/DDE.

Comment: I'm specifically asking about the Windows version, though.